# Mock "socket.socket.connect" method to assert it was called with given parameters while keeping functionality

Tags: python, django, sockets, mocking

I'm using Python 2.7 and the mock library to test if the `connect` method of an object instance of `socket.socket` class is called with certain arguments. However I want to use the mock only as a "marker" and continue with the function call normally. In the case below, I want `socket.socket.connect` to call to the real non-patched function as a "side-effect" so the method doesn't fail later.

That is, I want a mock of the `socket.socket` class keeping the same functionality and behaviour but with the extra ability of recording the calls.

Here is the (simplified) test. This is what I think I got wrong:

```
# test.py
@patch('socket.socket.connect')
@override_settings(SERVER_IP='127.0.0.1')
def test_ip_from_settings(self, connect_mock):
    """
    The IP to connect to is taken from the Django settings.
    """
    def connect(self, address):
        socket.socket.connect(self, address)
    connect_mock.side_effect = connect

    result = connections.get_result()

    connect_mock.assert_called_with(('127.0.0.1', TCP_PORT))
```

And for reference, this is the (again simplified) code to connect and retrieve the results:

```
# connections.py
from django.conf import settings
def get_result():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((settings.SERVER_IP, TCP_PORT))

    query = 'myquery'
    s.sendall(query)
    result = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    return result
```

However when running the test `TypeError: connect() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`is raised. How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [mocking unbound method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-unbound-methods) you must use `autospec=True` to preserve the signature.... But unfortunately `socket.socket.connect()` cannot be mocked [because is a C method](http://code.google.com/p/mock/source/browse/mock.py#197). But our goal is not mock it but just wrap it by a mock. So the simplest but not really clean trick that I found was use a new class to fool mock framework

```
from mock import ANY

class MyS():
    def connect(self, address): #The signature
        pass

@patch("socket.socket.connect", autospec=MyS.connect, side_effect=socket.socket.connect)
@override_settings(SERVER_IP='127.0.0.1')
def test_ip_from_settings(self, connect_mock):
    """
    The IP to connect to is taken from the Django settings.
    """
    result = connections.get_result()
    connect_mock.assert_called_with(ANY,('127.0.0.1', TCP_PORT))
```

You must use `ANY` from mock helpers because you don't know what socket object will be passed to your wrapper.

That trick works either for Python3 and Python2.7 but in Python3 the behavior is little bit different because `socket.socket.connect()` is not a function but a `method_descriptor`.

```
>>> import socket
>>> type(socket.socket.connect)
<class 'method_descriptor'>
```

Also in that case use `autospec=True` doesn't work.

---

The real question is : are you sure you need a *real connection* to make your tests. Mock aims is uncouple testing from real resources, register calls and assert on arguments is a plus but the first use is replace real object by mocks that are simple, fast and can be configured to return what we need for testing defined behaviors.

Maybe what you really need is `patch()` `socket.socket` and set some `return_values` or `side_effect` to drive your test in the cases you would test.

Comment: You're right. I just wanted the real connection to happen because later I do `socket.sendall(...)` and I wanted that to work. But I might as well mock the entire socket class with `send(..)`, `sendall(..)`, `recv()` etc. methods.

Comment: In Python 3.3+, you can simply `import unittest.mock` as `mock` is now included in the standard library: docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: @phoenix the issue is not how import `mock` in python 3 but that in python 3 you cannot use `autospec=True` for `socket.socket.connect`.... but maybe I'll come back later to this answer and try to use `wraps` instead: it should be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

The inner function `connect` inside the method `test_ip_from_settings` is not a method but a function. So you must remove the first argument `self`.

This:

`def connect(self, address):
    socket.socket.connect(self, address)`

Should be:

`def connect(address):
    socket.socket.connect(address)`

This is because of that when you call `s.connect((settings.SERVER_IP, TCP_PORT))`, the tuple `(settings.SERVER_IP, TCP_PORT)` is one argument, which goes to `self` argument in your case and then `address` variable still needs to be specified.

In the second correct case, there is no `self` argument, so the tuple is bound to `address` argument.

Comment: Ok, but if I do that then I get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Anyhow I don't understand how can I "mark-mock" the `connect` method keeping the original behaviour without a reference to self.

Comment: That doesn't preserve the original behaviour as requested in the question. I want to patch the `socket.socket` class to get the same behaviour as the original one but recording the calls.